# Is it possible to delay a TCP ACK at the server side in its way back to the client?

Tags: logging, tcp

I am testing the TCP protocol to check its reliability under link and node failures, I want to test what if an ACK lost in its way back to the client, but ACK response is very fast, I want to delay it some seconds in order to get the Ethernet cable off. 
Is there any way to delay the ACK, or any other way to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Test your application. Don't test the platform. The giys have tests for that. Don't waste your time. If you find a platform bug, what exactly are you going to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to tell your kernel to delay the ACK.  You can be certain that there will be a number of retries if the ACK is lost and the connection appears to stall from the perspective of either side.

If you are determined to test TCP/IP, you can do what you are asking if you use a tool like Scapy to build your own simple TCP/IP stack implementation.  If you do so, be sure to configure your host based firewall to prevent RST packets from being sent.  Here's a simple example of completing a three way handshake in response to a SYN to any port:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *

# My starting sequence number
sequence=100

# Wait for an inbound syn
packets=sniff(filter="tcp[13]&0x02 != 0", count=1, iface="eth0")
syn = packets[0]
my_ack = syn.getlayer("TCP").seq + 1
dest = syn.getlayer("IP").src
sport = syn.getlayer("TCP").dport
dport = syn.getlayer("TCP").sport

target = IP(dst=dest)
tcp_layer = TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, ack=my_ack, seq=sequence, flags="SA")
response = sr1(target/tcp_layer)
synack = response[0]
target = IP(dst=dest)
tcp_layer=TCP(sport=sport, dport=dport, ack=my_ack, seq=sequence, flags="A")
send(target/tcp_layer)
```

Comment: very helpful, great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delay the response ack (input packet) using `tc` and add a delay on the igress interface.